# Extracting numbers from a String in Java by splitting on a regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract numbers from Strings like this:

```
String numbers[] = "M0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901,-0.436,,,123,0.123,.34".split(PATTERN);
```

From such String I'd like to extract these numbers:

- 0.286
- -3.099
- -0.44
- -2.901
- -0.436
- 123
- 0.123
- .34

That is:

- There can be garbage characters like "M", "c", "c"
- The "-" sign is to include in the number, not to split on
- A "number" can be anything that `Float.parseFloat` can parse, so `.34` is valid

What I have so far:

```
String PATTERN = "([^\\d.-]+)|(?=-)";
```

Which works to some degree, but obviously far from perfect:

- Doesn't skip the starting garbage "M" in the example
- Doesn't handle consecutive garbage, like the `,,,` in the middle

How to fix PATTERN to make it work?

Comment: "...by splitting on a regex" do you mean you must use `yourString.split(regex)`, or `while(matcher.find()){...}` is also acceptable solution? I would be against `split` in this case because it could create additional empty element at start of result array like in case `"notNumber123NotNumber".split(regexForNotNumber)` would return `["", "123"]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
([-.]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dM0yY9/1)**

[image]

Match Information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-6]   `0.286`
MATCH 2
1.  [6-12]  `-3.099`
MATCH 3
1.  [12-17] `-0.44`
MATCH 4
1.  [18-24] `-2.901`
MATCH 5
1.  [25-31] `-0.436`
MATCH 6
1.  [34-37] `123`
MATCH 7
1.  [38-43] `0.123`
MATCH 8
1.  [44-47] `.34`
```

**Update**

### **[Jawee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881173/jawee)**'s approach

As **[Jawee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3881173/jawee)** pointed in his comment there is a problem for `.34.34`, so you can use his regex that fix this problem. Thanks Jawee to point out that.

```
(-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)
```

To have graphic idea about what happens behind this regex you can check this [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bCF6zKTfuuGtLV9X)
 image:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Engine explanation:**

```
1st Capturing group (-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)
   -? -> matches the character - literally zero and one time
   (?:\d+)? -> \d+ match a digit [0-9] one and unlimited times (using non capturing group)
   \.? matches the character . literally zero and one time
   \d+ match a digit [0-9] one and unlimited times
```

Comment: This finds matches, OP wants to *split*. (Considering the OP knows about look-arounds, I bet he could have come up with this pattern himself it it was what he was after)

Comment: It seems that if test string is ".34.34", the result is one match as ".34.34", not two match ".34" ".34". Another try could be "(-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)". FYI

Comment: Thanks @jawee to point out that. I've updated the answer with your comments

Comment: Your second one fails to match `23.`, which is a valid number for `parseFloat`.

Comment: @nhahtdh I understand your point but not all cases can be covered. For instance, if you have `3.123` you could think of three values `3.`, `.123` or `3.123`, so I based on OP samples to cover as most scenarios as possible. Feel free to post an answer so OP can see other approaches

Comment: @Fede: jawee's edited answer should take care of all those cases. As long as you got the search order right, it will never have a partial match. (Using your example 3.123, as long as you search for `\d+\.\d+` before `\d+\.` and `\d+`, then you will always find `3.123`. The `\.\d+` case won't even be considered unless there is no preceding digit.)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one `(-?(?:\d+)?\.?\d+)`
Example as below:

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/fS0lG1/2)

Thanks a lot for **[nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh)**'s comments. That's true, we could update as below:

```
[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)
```

[Updated Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/fS0lG1/4)

Actually, if we take all possible float input String format (e.g: `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `00`, `0xffp23d`, `88F`), then it could be a little bit complicated. However, we still could implement it as below Java code:

```
String sign = "[-+]?";
String hexFloat = "(?>0[xX](((\\p{XDigit}+)\\.?)|((\\p{XDigit}*)\\.(\\p{XDigit}+)))[pP]([-+])?(\\p{Digit}+)[fFdD]?)";
String nan = "(?>NaN)";
String inf = "(?>Infinity)";

String dig = "(?>\\d+(?:\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+)";
String exp = "(?:[eE][-+]?\\d+)?";
String suf = "[fFdD]?";
String digFloat = "(?>" + dig + exp + suf + ")";

String wholeFloat = sign + "(?>" + hexFloat + "|" + nan + "|" + inf + "|" + digFloat + ")";

String s = "M0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901,-0.436,,,123,0.123d,.34d.34.34M24.NaNNaN,Infinity,-Infinity00,0xffp23d,88F";

Pattern floatPattern = Pattern.compile(wholeFloat);
Matcher matcher = floatPattern.matcher(s);
int i = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    String f =  matcher.group();
    System.out.println(i++ + " : " + f + " --- " +  Float.parseFloat(f) );
}
```

Then the output is as below:

```
0 : 0.286 --- 0.286
1 : -3.099 --- -3.099
2 : -0.44 --- -0.44
3 : -2.901 --- -2.901
4 : -0.436 --- -0.436
5 : 123 --- 123.0
6 : 0.123d --- 0.123
7 : .34d --- 0.34
8 : .34 --- 0.34
9 : .34 --- 0.34
10 : 24. --- 24.0
11 : NaN --- NaN
12 : NaN --- NaN
13 : Infinity --- Infinity
14 : -Infinity --- -Infinity
15 : 00 --- 0.0
16 : 0xffp23d --- 2.13909504E9
17 : 88F --- 88.0
```

Comment: Your regex fails to match `23.`, which is a valid number for `parseFloat`.

Comment: Although your solution not wrong, matching decimal digits can be done with `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)` - it will match all formats `23`, `34.`, `34.2`, `.34`. And well, the suffix seems to be a Java thing, so it is arguable whether you want to parse it.

Comment: @nhahtdh many thanks! Your're right, your solution are more succinct for decimal digits. If possible, please update my answers using your solution!

Answer (score 2):

Using the regex you crafted yourself you can solve it as follows:

```
String[] numbers = "M0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901,-0.436,,,123,0.123,.34"
                          .replaceAll(PATTERN, " ")
                          .trim()
                          .split(" +");
```

On the other hand, if I were you, I'd do the loop instead:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[.-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?").matcher(input);
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find())
    matches.add(m.group());
```

Comment: +1 I disagree: I think your one-liner is best, and better than [the way I normally do it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26225571/256196)

Comment: This regex will match `.34.34` as one token, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line (but with one less step than aioobe's answer!):

```
String[] numbers = "M0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901,-0.436,,,123,0.123,.34"
    .replaceAll("^[^.\\d-]+|[^.\\d-]+$", "") // remove junk from start/end
    .split("[^.\\d-]+"); // split on anything not part of a number
```

Although less calls are made, aioobe's answer is easier to read and understand, which makes his better code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what you want:

```
String pattern = "[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+";
String line = "M0.286-3.099-0.44c-2.901,-0.436,,,123,0.123,.34";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
List<String> numbers=new ArrayList<String>();

while(m.find()) {
    numbers.add(m.group());         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its nice you put a bounty on this.
Unfortunately, as you probably already know, this can't be done using
Java's string split method directly.

If it can't be done directly, there is no reason to kludge it as it is, well .. a kludge.

The reasons are many, some related, some not.

To start off, you need to define a good regex as a base.
This is the only regex I know that will validate and extract a proper form:

```
 # "((?=[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d)[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)"

 (                             # (1 start)
      (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
      [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
 )                             # (1 end)
```

So, looking at this base regex, its clear you want this form that it matches.
In the case of split, you **don't** want the form that this matches, because that's
where you want the breaks to be.

As I look at Java's split, I see that no matter what it matches, **it** will be excluded
from the resulting array.

So, presuming split usage, the first thing to match (and consume) is all the stuff that is not
this.  That part will be something like this:

```
 (?:
      (?!
           (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
           [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
      )
      . 
 )+
```

Since the only thing left is **valid** decimal numbers, the next break will be somewhere
between valid numbers.  This part, added to the first part, will be something like this:

```
 (?:
      (?!
           (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
           [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
      )
      . 
 )+
 |         # or,
 (?<=
      (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
      [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
 )
 (?=
      (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
      [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
 )
```

And all of a sudden, we have a problem .. **a variable length lookbehind assertion**
So, its game over for the whole thing.

Lastly and unfortunately, Java does not (as far as I can see) have a provision to include capture
group contents (matched in the regex) as an element in the resulting array.
Perl does, but I can't find that ability in Java.

If Java had that provision, the break sub expressions could be combined to do a seamless split.
Like this:

```
 (?:
      (?!
           (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
           [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
      )
      . 
 )*
 (
      (?= [+-]? \d* \.? \d )
      [+-]? \d* \.? \d* 
 )
```

Comment: I like the effort you spend into this, but the straightforward solution to the lack of provision is to break this into two steps, which is more effective in this case than your Qtax trick, anyway.

Comment: @Unihedro - The problem is it's impossible to break this into two steps. If it could, both steps would have to incorporate numeric validity `(?=[+-]?\d*\.?\d)[+-]?\d*\.?\d*`. In the end, doing the same thing twice is pointless. If you think there is a two step process, I'd be interested to debunk it.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. I awarded the bounty to the answer I originally intended to. I started a new bounty, to award to you tomorrow. (SO makes me wait 24 hours)

Comment: Your regex with the variable length look-behind is totally bogus, since it will match the empty string in between a string of numbers `234235` (using .NET tester).

Comment: Another thing - in languages which supports splitting, the split regex at the end is not seamless - it will produce a bunch of empty strings in between.

Comment: @nhahtdh - The only language I know of that support turning capture buffers into elements is Perl. By seamless, I meant the non-numbers are filtered side by side with captured number. There is no other construct. Perl always inserts a preceding empty element with the captured element. Its can always be grepped out like this `@ary = grep { length } split/(?=[+-]?\d*\.?\d)([+-]?\d*\.?\d*)/, $teststr;`

Comment: @nhahtdh - Yep, the bogus (?<=)(?=) assertions won't work since there is no way to advance the position in side by side valid numbers (other than bump along). So I guess I should have mentioned that too. Result, another reason it can't be done with split !!

Comment: Splitting with capture element placed in the result array is done by at least JavaScript and .NET.