# How to extract doubles or integers from a string java

Tags: java, regex, string

Im writing this code in which the user enters a string which contains numbers, e.g.

```
H3.07LLo my nam3 is bob12
```

And the output should be

```
3.07, 3.0, 12.0
```

I've managed to get a regular expression to look for doubles, but I don't know how to look for ints. this is my regex:

```
(-)?(([^\\d])(0)|[1-9][0-9]*)(.)([0-9]+)
```

I'm pretty new to regex. I tried adding `|[0-9]|` but I keep on messing it up wherever I put it in my current regex

Comment: One similar question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225235/extracting-numbers-from-a-string-in-java-by-splitting-on-a-regex" for your reference!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line by replacing non-numeric characters with space, trimming then splitting on space.

```
String[] numbers = str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]+", " ").trim().split(" ");
```

That gives you the parts of the input that are numbers. If you then actually need doubles:

```
double[] ds = new double[numbers.length];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { 
    ds[i] = Double.parseDouble(numbers[i]);
}
```

For some java 8 fun, the whole thing can be done in one line!

```
double[] nums = Arrays.stream(str.replaceAll("[^0-9.]+", " ").trim().split(" ")).mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
```

Comment: What if the text is `123.21.212.554aaaaa5`? `numbers` will be `["123.21.212.554", "5"]`

Comment: Good observation, I'd say in that case you just filter out any results with more than one dot.  I like this approach for its simplicity, even if it does have the one problem mentioned above.

Comment: Also, you should use the proper `Locale` in order to parse doubles with `.` as decimal separator, otherwise it will work only for those locales which use `.` as separator. (Use the french locale, you'll see it won't work).

Comment: @BackSlash true, but what would you propose to do with such input for any solution? Eg should "123.456.7" be parsed as "123.4" and "56.7" *or* "123.4" and "56.7"? I consider such input to be "bad" input, unless there's a clear definition of how to interpret adjacent numbers, which is not mentioned or implied in the question.

Comment: @BackSlash good pint about the locale, but that can be added by the coder. This is just a basic impl.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
(-?[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?)
```

Explanation:

```
NODE                       EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -?                     '-' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                 any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                    group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [,.]                 any character of: ',', '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+               any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/mR4iS6/1)

Comment: are using any tool to generate this doc?

Comment: @kamoor [`This way`](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28-%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%2C.%5D%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%29)

Comment: Ive just tried it and it works but Im not sure how you made the ints turn into a double by that regex. How are you adding a .0 to the ints?

Comment: @user3323950 the pattern will grab ints (left part) and IF these digits are followed by a dot and some more digits, it will grab those too which will give a decimal... this last part is optional hint the use of `?` which means 0 or 1 time

Answer (score 1):

There is one problem in your regex which is using the dot (`.`) character to match the literal dot. The dot character is a special symbol in regex terminology that matches *any* character. In order to only match the decimal point `.`, you need to escape it using `\.`.

To match an integer, you could make the group consisting of the decimal point and the fractional digits to be optional, using the question mark symbol. There is also no need for parentheses unless you're grouping patterns. So your regex could be simply `-?(\d+)(\.\d+)?`.

```
String input = "H3.07LLo my nam3 is bob12";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(Double.valueOf(matcher.group()));
}
```

**Output:**

```
3.07
3.0
12.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I need the integers to be doubles so i'd need 3.07, 3.0, 12.0 etc but Im not sure how to add those through regex